# Error 4430 when overloading << operator

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to overload the << operator for a homework project. I keep getting an error code 4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-in. Any help would be great!

```
//EmployeeInfo is designed to hold employee ID information

#ifndef EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#define EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const EmployeeInfo &);

class EmployeeInfo
{
private: 
    int empID;
    string empName;

public:
    //Constructor
    EmployeeInfo();

    //Member Functions
    void setName(string);
    void setID(int);
    void setEmp(int, string);
    int getId();
    string getName();
    string getEmp(int &);

    //operator overloading
    bool operator < (const EmployeeInfo &);
    bool operator >  (const EmployeeInfo &);
    bool operator == (const EmployeeInfo &);

    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const EmployeeInfo &);
};

friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const EmployeeInfo &right)
{
    strm << right.empID << "\t" << right.empName;
    return strm;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Does your compiler indicate what line the error corresponds to? If so, what line?

Comment: First, check friend `std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const EmployeeInfo &right)`
 definition. `friend` is not allowed outside of the class.

Comment: And 'operator <<' declaration and definition are different. Change definition to: `std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const EmployeeInfo &) { ... }`

Comment: Finally, you can remove `operator <<` forward declaration, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with this line:

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const EmployeeInfo &);
```

This line appears before the declaration of the `EmployeeInfo` class. In other words, the compiler doesn't yet know what an `EmployeeInfo` is. You either need to move that declaration to a point after the class declaration, or "pre-declare" the class like so:

```
class EmployeeInfo; // "Pre-declare" this class

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const EmployeeInfo &);

class EmployeeInfo
{
    // ... as you have now ...
};
```

Comment: I see what your talking about. I changed it around, but am still getting the error. It seems the compiler is not  recognizing ostream as a data type.